# Can I send multiple uploaded attachments from a Google Form/Google Sheet in an automated email?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am trying to create a Google Form linked to a Google Sheet utilizing some Google App script that will take some answers from a survey, **attach an uploaded file**, and send an email to a specific person. I have been able to figure out the part where I collect the data in a Google Sheet and send an email, but the part where I take the uploaded file and have it as an attachment in the email is stumping me.

Currently, my code to send the email looks like this:

```
GmailApp.sendEmail(Recipient,subject,'',{htmlBody: htmlText},);
```

But looking at [the documentation on sendEmail](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail%28String,String,String,Object%29), it looks like I want to add more to that Options part, right? The so if I am defining a variable for this, I need to use getFileById, but the file ID will be different with each upload. Furthermore, I might need to attach multiple files.

I have created a test [Google Form here](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/188E72tVXYcPl9XKZcTEOyHBsUsRz1Zg9GL3TY_Rshj4/edit) and I have attached it to [a Google Sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15QOhFNd4P7M1ibWoXSt9oEEDvAvmItwK4A_VHzqGZu8/edit#gid=1100855539). You can see [the Google App Script here](https://script.google.com/home/projects/1FGYtwxC37l_kJfhsfoYnxIQcdg3GuFubZzi-BF5QUoEES9nZkIGj_dxH/edit). You can check the email being sent/received successfully by looking at formtesting4@mailinator.com as specified in the code.

Is that possible with what I am trying to do?

Comment: Hi I noticed that you are trying to create an html table. What kind of attachment do you plan to do? include uploaded file links under Attachment block in your html body? or  attach the file in the email itself not in the html body (using attachments option)?

Comment: The HTML table is in the body of the email. I could just include the links to the uploaded files by referencing the appropriate cell, but I would like to attach the file(s) to the email itself. I should have made this clearer, but I would like to build functionality so that it could handle multiple files if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can refer to this sample script:

```
function emailMe() {

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  const info = ss.getDataRange().getValues();

  info.forEach((entry,a) => {

    // Identify whether notification has been sent
    if (entry[4] === '') {


      // Collect entries
      var Recipient = "your@email.com"
      var subject = 'Roster Scheduler Update';
      Timestamp = entry[0];
      Name = entry[1];
      Roster = entry[2];
      attachment = "TEST";
      
      var attachmentBlobs = [];
      //Get the blob of all attachments available
      if(entry[3]){
        var attachments = entry[3].split(', ');
      
        attachments.forEach(url => {
          var fileId = url.replace('https://drive.google.com/open?id=','');
          Logger.log(fileId);
          var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
          attachmentBlobs.push(file.getBlob());
        });
      }
 
      let body = '';

      // Generate email
      var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("email.html");
      var htmlText = html.evaluate().getContent();
      
      // Send email
      GmailApp.sendEmail(Recipient, subject, body, {htmlBody: htmlText, attachments: attachmentBlobs});

      // Email confidence
      const check = 'Sent';
      ss.getRange(a + 1,5).setValue(check);

    }
  });
}
```

### Changes done:

- Get the blob file of all the uploaded attachments using [File.getBlob()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getblob). You can get the file id from the attachment's url link and use [DriveApp.getFileById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilebyidid)
- Include `body` in the `GmailApp.sendEmail()` to fix email content issue
- Include `attachments` as an option in the  [GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options)

### Output:

**Sample1: 3 attachments**

[image]

**Sample2: 1 attachment**

[image]

Comment: So it looks like that works UNLESS someone doesn't upload an attachment. I probably should've clarified, but it won't always be a requirement to have an attachment uploaded to the Google Form. I'm assuming enclosing it in some kind of IF statement for the attachment variable would suffice?

Comment: Yes just an if condition will be sufficient. I updated the answer. Please let me know if there is still some issues

Comment: Perfect. That covers everything. Thank you so much for sticking with me. I'm going to go read some documentation on these classes and methods to learn more on them.

The only thing I added was an additional 

`else {
attachment = "No attachment submitted"
}`

To account for an empty submission.